# How to get Email ID/Account through which my app has been purchased?

Tags: android, google-play

I want email id or account of google play store which is used to purchase my app. I am planning to use that email id as user id of my app.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hey,Bipin Did you find any way to achieve this?If yes ,please share.If not you can share a workaround